# How to remove header on the page with big picture (or a page containing floats)?

Tags: floats, header-footer, fancyhdr, rotating

Can you help me to remove header from the page where is only one big picture? I tried `\thispagestyle{empty}` but it removes a header on the next or previous page. I don't know how to remove it exactly from the page only with the picture.
I put this picture in my document by using `{sidewaysfigure}` environment and `\includegraphics` in it.

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[
 centering,
 top=12mm,
 headheight=14pt,
 headsep=11pt,
 includeheadfoot,
 papersize={160mm,235mm},
 text={125mm,190.7mm},
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} 
\newcommand{\TheAuthor}{} 
\newcommand{\Author}[1]{\renewcommand{\TheAuthor}{#1}} 
\rhead{\small\TheAuthor}
\newcommand{\TheTitle}{} 
\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\renewcommand{\TheTitle}{#1}} 
\lhead{\small\normalfont\TheTitle}
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{rotating}


\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
   \centering
   \fbox{\includegraphics[width=190mm]{pic.jpg}}  
   \caption*{\footnotesize\centering{Pic. 1}}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does putting `\thispagestyle{empty}` inside the float evironment work?

Comment: @Seamus, unfortunatelly it doesn't work.

Comment: @kotspot: See my answer -- use `\iffloatpage` as part of your header definitions. For example (using your MWE): `\rhead{\iffloatpage{}{\small\TheAuthor}}`

Comment: See also: [How to get a big table on a page with pagestyle empty?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/how-to-get-a-big-table-on-a-page-with-pagestyle-empty/158710)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you use the [`rotating`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating) package, i.e., that `sidewaysfigure` is a floating environment, `fancyhdr`'s `\iffloatpage` macro should do the trick.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\iffloatpage{}{(The Title)}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\iffloatpage{}{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{\iffloatpage{0pt}{0.4pt}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[8]

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A rotated figure}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

(The [`blindtext`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext/) package is only used to add some dummy text to the example.)

EDIT: In your subsequently delivered MWE, replace

```
\rhead{\small\TheAuthor}
```

...

```
\lhead{\small\normalfont\TheTitle}
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
```

with

```
\rhead{\iffloatpage{}{\small\TheAuthor}}
```

...

```
\lhead{\iffloatpage{}{\small\normalfont\TheTitle}}
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\iffloatpage{}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{\iffloatpage{0pt}{0.4pt}}
```

Comment: it works, but can you tell me how to adapt it to my {fancyhdr} options? I don't want to lose them. I try to use it but don't know how.

Comment: @kotspot: I just noticed that you have accepted a few answers in the past, but never cast a vote so far. Please consider upvoting those answers (and answers to other questions you find useful). You have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: thanks for your help! Now it works great. Could you explain me what's going on with this upvoting. I'm still new here.

Comment: @kotspot: You upvote questions and answers you find useful by clicking at the upward pointing arrow to the left of it. (There's also an arrow for downvoting -- if you do so, consider to leave a comment explaining the reasons.) You can cast up to 30 votes per day.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `\mergepagefloatstyle` from the `memoir` document class. See [my post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158710/6805) in a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

use package `afterpage` and write somewhere on the page before:

```
\afterpage{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

Comment: unfortunatelly \afterpage hasn't resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem – in my case `\clearpage \thispagestyle{empty}` did the trick.

Comment: Well, can you please add an MWE to show how it solves the **given** problem? What was your case? The exactly same problem or different? Please just explain better what you mean and Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Same here. Although I had to use `\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}`, otherwise following `\begin{figure}[H]` appeared after an entire empty page.