# How to get a big table on a page with pagestyle empty?

Tags: floats, header-footer, fancyhdr

In my document I have a table that is quite big. I would like to have this table on a page with no header and no page number. How can I get this table on a `\thispagestyle{empty}`? Using it withing the table or tabular environment makes the page were the float is defined go empty and leaves the headers on the table.

For if it matters, I am using `fancyhdr`.

Comment: see also: [Suppress page number for a single page that only contains one large table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33007/579)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fancyhdr` provides the `\iffloatpage` macro that can be used to customize header and footer for pages which contain only floats.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\iffloatpage{}{\slshape\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\iffloatpage{}{\slshape\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\iffloatpage{}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{\iffloatpage{0pt}{0.4pt}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\begin{table}[p]
\centering
(Table contents)
\caption{A table on a separate page}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: For those that want to use the `\iffloatpage` macro with KOMA-script's `scrpage2` package instead of with `fancyhdr`, add the following to your preamble (thanks to Stefan Kottwitz for the tip):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\iffloatpage}[2]{\if@fcolmade #1\else #2\fi}
\makeatother
```

(The [blindtext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext/) package is only used to add some dummy text to the example.)

Comment: @Peter: By default, the table should be vertically centered. Tweaking the positioning paramaters still won't "reclaim" the header space, unless the table is too large for a normal page to begin with. There may be hacks to achieve what you want, but that's over my head.

Comment: Thanks for that. I realized this immediately after I posted my comment, so therefore I removed it :)

Answer (score 4):

When using the [memoir](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) document class the command `mergepagefloatstyle` can be used to separate pagestyles for regular pages and pages with only floats, similar to @lockstep's soltuion. For example

```
\mergepagefloatstyle{floatcomp}{ruled}{empty}
```

defines a new style `floatcomp` that will use the pagestyle `ruled` for regular pages and `empty` for float-only pages.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

% Define new style floatcomp that usees 'ruled' style for regular
% pages, and 'empty' for float-only pages.
\mergepagefloatstyle{floatcomp}{ruled}{empty}
% Use previously defined floatcomp style
\pagestyle{floatcomp}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-5]

\begin{table}[p]
\centering
(Table contents)
\caption{A table on a separate page}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\kant[10-13]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply put the table on a page of its own without putting it inside a `table` environment.  Then you can make use `\thispagestyle{empty}` before the table. To add the caption properly, use the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no really satisfying answer to the question yet, I want to add an alternative to Alan's approach.

```
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}
\clearpage
```

This lets you keep the "float" as such, it just doesn't float anymore. That kinda sucks but this at least gives you another poison to choose from.