# Suppress page number for a single page that only contains one large table?

Tags: floats, header-footer, page-numbering

I have a large table that uses up the whole space on a page. Unfortunately, the table also covers the page number, which is shining through. I don't want to split the table across two pages, hence I want to suppress the page numbering for this single page. Here's my table source code:

```
\begin{table}
    \myfloatalign
    \begin{tabular}[t]{rrrrr}
        % lots
        % of
        % rows
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I tried to place a `\thispagestyle{empty}` right before the table, directly after the table and in various other places, but without success.

How do I suppress the page number of the page that contains the table?

Comment: Do you have control on where the table will appear in the document, or do you want it to float freely?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The behaviour you expierence is because the table is typeset first on the current page, so a `\thispagestyle` before or after applies to that page, but then it floats to the next page where it is displayed.

In order to make this work use the `floatpag` package with `\floatpagestyle{empty}` to make all float pages have an empty style or use `\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}` *inside* the float, i.e. the `table` environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer. Your solution works perfectly well.

Comment: Hi, @MartinScharrer. Your solution worked for me. However, for the numbered float pages, their position was modified to top right. Can I define it to bottom center? Thank you.

Comment: I had the same issue as @pceccon. This is due to the `floatpag` package defaulting to `\floatpagestyle{headings}`. You can use `\floatpagestyle{plain}` to get the bottom-center page numbers (and `\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}` as necessary to suppress page numbers).

Comment: how to hide only page number and keep top header?

Comment: @user3806649: Depends on your setup. Please post a follow-up question and provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the `afterpage` package and its command `\afterpage`; the method is admittedly a bit kludgy, but I've used it over the years to very good effect in just the types of situations you describe.

```
... material before large table ...
\afterpage{ % execute argument of this command *after* end of current page
\clearpage % clear any pending floats
\begin{table}
...
\end{table}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage % force a page break
} % end of \afterpage{...} stuff
... remainder of document ...
```

The only way this might fail is if you already have other floats queued up, waiting to be typeset on a page, before you get to the `\afterpage{}` command. If that's the case, just issue a second `\clearpage` command. :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can change the page style for *all* float-only pages using the package `fancyhdr`. It provides the construction `\iffloatpage{value for float page}{value for other pages}`. See the [documentation for `fancyhdr`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf), section 14.

Another option is to use float package and the provided `H` placement specifier to put your table on a non-floating page.  Then you can use `\thispagestyle` on this page.  Of course it means you are to control the placement of the table yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answer from Boris, I got it working by adding the following to my preamble

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\iffloatpage{}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```