# Centralize cell contents vertically in a big and wide table without changing the horizontal alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a very big (wide and long) table that want to show in only one page. I did not want to convert it to figure, or change the fonts. So I shrank the table margins (without shrinking the contents) and used some extra margins of the page as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 2pt}}

\begin{document}
This is the first page. Please see the second page; 

it has a long table that we want to centralize its cell contents vertically without changing its horizontal alignments.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.45}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \vspace*{-85pt}
  \centering
  \caption{Comparison of the results}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} %if need to shrink more, reduce to 2.2
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c?r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \hline
    Method & Project & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\# of devs} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\# of bugs} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Top1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Top5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{P@1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{r@1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{p@5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{r@5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{p@10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{r@10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{MRR} \bigstrut\\
    \hline \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    Method 1 and method 2 & All projects & 75-4,079 & 566-16,184 & 47    & 75    & 46.99 & 40.83 & 17.15 & 71.75 & 9.81 & 81.63 & 0.54 \bigstrut\\
    \hline \Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &     66  &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       & 11 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{ Method 6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{ Method 6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{ Method 6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{ Method 6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{adjustbox}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{6pt} %Original left and right margins.
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
  \vspace*{-85pt}
\end{table}%
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\pagebreak
This is the third page. Please see the second page. 
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

> First page:

[image]

> Second page:

[image]

> Third page:

[image]

Now, there are two problems;

1. The horizontal alignment of all the cells is okay.

   Also for the vertical alignment of multirow items are good.

   But the "one-row" cells are not exactly in the middle of the cells (vertically). They are close to top of the cells. I used `m{2cm}` instead of `r` after `\begin{tabular}{|c|c?r|...` but it changes the horizontal alignments and also does not align the items vertically.

   How can I centralize the cell contents vertically without changing the horizontal alignment, and without changing the whole table's position?
2. I wanted to hide the page number in the second page (because of its overlap with the table), so I used `\thispagestyle{empty}`. But it removed the page number in the first page.

   How can I hide the page number *just* in the second page?

I appreciate any ideas or solutions.

Comment: Try using the `afterpage` package as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33007/suppress-page-number-for-a-single-page-that-only-contains-one-large-table

Comment: Why are you using `\bigstrut`? At least for your table it seams, that the output looks better if you set `\arraystrech` up to like 0.85 and remove all `\bigstrut`. Then it is still not perfect but better for the normal lines. But the multi row items then don't work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit:* I have just seen an easier solution so I thought I will add it on top of my post here. You could use `\setlength\extrarowheight{...pt}`.

---

---

Ok this time I fixed your problem without proposing a completely new table. I added the `array` package and used `>{\llap{\phantom{\textsuperscript{2}}}}` on the columns. `\llap` so that the inserted space dose not widen our column or influence the positioning of the text and `\phantom` because we just want to add space not actual text. With `\textsuperscript{2}` we trick the cells into believing that there is superscript text so that LaTeX is forced to provide us more space at the top. I then further lowered the `\arraystretch`.
The problem of the page number is again fixed by inserting `\clearpage` before and after the tabular

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 2pt}}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
This is the first page. Please see the second page; 

it has a long table that we want to centralize its cell contents vertically without changing its horizontal alignments.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.13}\clearpage
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \vspace*{-85pt}
  \centering
  \caption{Comparison of the results}
%  \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} %if need to shrink more, reduce to 2.2
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c? *{11}{ >{\llap{\phantom{\textsuperscript{2}}}}r| }}
    \hline
    Method & Proj & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\# of devs} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\# of bugs} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Top1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Top5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{P@1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{r@1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{p@5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{r@5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{p@10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{r@10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{MRR} \bigstrut\\
    \hline \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    Method 1 \& 2 & All & 75-4,079 & 566-16,184 & 47    & 75    & 46.99 & 40.83 & 17.15 & 71.75 & 9.81 & 81.63 & 0.54 \bigstrut\\
    \hline \Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &     66  &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       & 11 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Method 6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Method 6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Method 6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Method 6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{adjustbox}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{6pt} %Original left and right margins.
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
  \vspace*{-85pt}
\end{table}%
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\clearpage
This is the third page. Please see the second page. 
\end{document}
```

The result looks good:

[image]

[image]

---

---

You can delete the `\bigstrut` commands from the above code and set `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}` to get the same result but without the need to always manually call `\bigstrut`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 2pt}}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
This is the first page. Please see the second page; 

it has a long table that we want to centralize its cell contents vertically without changing its horizontal alignments.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}\clearpage
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \vspace*{-85pt}
  \centering
  \caption{Comparison of the results}
%  \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} %if need to shrink more, reduce to 2.2
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c? *{11}{ >{\llap{\phantom{\textsuperscript{2}}}}r| }}
    \hline
    Method & Proj & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\# of devs} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\# of bugs} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Top1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Top5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{P@1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{r@1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{p@5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{r@5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{p@10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{r@10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{MRR} \\
    \hline \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    Method 1 \& 2 & All & 75-4,079 & 566-16,184 & 47    & 75    & 46.99 & 40.83 & 17.15 & 71.75 & 9.81 & 81.63 & 0.54 \\
    \hline \Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &     66  &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       & 11 \\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Method 6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \\
    \hline
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Method 6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \\
    \hline
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Method 6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \\
    \hline
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{Method 6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \\
    \hline
    Method 3 & P & 1510  & 69,829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[14]{*}{Method 4} & Q & 3,014  & 188,139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 2,144  & 177,637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Y & 1,695  & 43,162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & X & 380   & 23,522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Z & 374   & 17,084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & P   & 293   & 19,430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & Q  & 156   & 34,220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{Method 5} & P & ?     & 549,962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \\
\cline{2-13}          & P & ?     & 306,297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{adjustbox}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{6pt} %Original left and right margins.
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
  \vspace*{-85pt}
\end{table}%
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\clearpage
This is the third page. Please see the second page. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

You could also define `\thispagestyle{empty}` inside the table environment. and get rid of all `\clearpage` or `\pagebreak` commands but at least in your MWE this leads to a false placement of the table. But in an actual Text where the pages are filled with text this might be the better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose a completely different table design with the use of `booktabs` and `siunitx`. The issue of the page numbering could be fixes by inserting `\clearpage` (assuming you know where you want to put the table exactly).

I know that is not exactly what you came for but maybe it is still helpful to you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
This is the first page. Please see the second page; 

it has a long table that we want to centralize its cell contents vertically without changing its horizontal alignments.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.65}
\clearpage %%%
\begin{table}[p]
  \vspace*{-85pt}
  \centering
  \caption{Comparison of the results}
  %\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} %if need to shrink more reduce to 2.2
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c S[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=6.0] S[table-format=2.2] S[table-format=2.2] *{7}{S[table-format=2.0]} @{}}
    \toprule
    Method & Proj. & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\# of devs} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\# of bugs} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Top1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Top5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{P@1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{r@1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p@5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{r@5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p@10} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{r@10} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{MRR} \\
    \midrule
    1 and 2 & All & {75-4079} & {566-16184} & 47    & 75    & {46.99} & {40.83} & {17.15} & {71.75} & {9.81} & {81.63} & {0.54} \\
    \cmidrule{1-13} 
     3 & P & 1510  & 69829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {4} & Q & 3014  & 188139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & X & 2144  & 177637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Y & 1695  & 43162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \\
         & X & 380   & 23522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Z & 374   & 17084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &     66  &  \\
         & P   & 293   & 19430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       & 11 \\
         & Q  & 156   & 34220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {5} & P & ?     & 549962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \\
         & P & ?     & 306297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \\
         & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
     3 & P & 1510  & 69829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {4} & Q & 3014  & 188139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & X & 2144  & 177637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Y & 1695  & 43162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \\
         & X & 380   & 23522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Z & 374   & 17084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \\
         & P   & 293   & 19430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Q  & 156   & 34220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {5} & P & ?     & 549962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \\
         & P & ?     & 306297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \\
         & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
     3 & P & 1510  & 69829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {4} & Q & 3014  & 188139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & X & 2144  & 177637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Y & 1695  & 43162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \\
         & X & 380   & 23522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Z & 374   & 17084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \\
         & P   & 293   & 19430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Q  & 156   & 34220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {5} & P & ?     & 549962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \\
         & P & ?     & 306297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \\
         & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
     3 & P & 1510  & 69829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {4} & Q & 3014  & 188139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & X & 2144  & 177637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Y & 1695  & 43162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \\
         & X & 380   & 23522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Z & 374   & 17084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \\
         & P   & 293   & 19430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Q  & 156   & 34220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {5} & P & ?     & 549962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \\
         & P & ?     & 306297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {6} & P & 58    & 100   & 14.4  & 48    &       &       &   20    &       &       &       &  \\
         & Q & 175   & 100   & 34.8  & 57.4  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & X & 40    & 100   & 7.2   & 45.6  &       &       &       &       &   12    &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
     3 & P & 1510  & 69829 & 37.81 & 68    &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {4} & Q & 3014  & 188139 & 29.9  & 71.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & X & 2144  & 177637 & 38.9  & 71.7  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Y & 1695  & 43162 & 40    & 78    &       &       &       &   10    &       &       &  \\
         & X & 380   & 23522 & 29.2  & 59.8  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Z & 374   & 17084 & 52.7  & 80    &       &       &    24   &       &       &       &  \\
         & P   & 293   & 19430 & 45.7  & 88.8  &       &   33    &       &       &       &       &  \\
         & Q  & 156   & 34220 & 30    & 73.2  &   47    &       &       &       &   44    &       &  \\
    \cmidrule{1-13}
    {5} & P & ?     & 549962 & 27.48 & 77.87 &       &       &       &    39   &       &       &  \\
         & P & ?     & 306297 & 32.99 & 77.43 &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
\end{adjustbox}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{6pt} %Original left and right margins.
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
  \vspace*{-85pt}
\end{table}%
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\clearpage%%%
This is the third page. Please see the second page. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your solution has a nicer view, but for unity with other tables and some other reasons I'd rather using the same look (i.e., full vertical and horizontal lines).