# what library to call \thisfloatpagestyle{empty} function?

Tags: page-numbering

i am trying to call the \thisfloatpagestyle{empty} function. 
[Suppress page number for a single page that only contains one large table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33007/suppress-page-number-for-a-single-page-that-only-contains-one-large-table)

but I get an error. below is my code. what library must i call to use that function ?

```
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\vspace*{-2.5cm}\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{20}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\footnotesize $}X<{$}}}
\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 & x_8 & x_9 & x_{10} & x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} & x_{15} & x_{16} & x_{17} & x_{18} & x_{19} & x_{20} \\ \\[-7ex]
\multicolumn{20}{c}{\subfloat[Ground Truth]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{results/ms.png}}}} \\
\hat{x_2} & \hat{x_3} & \hat{x_4} & \hat{x_5} & \hat{x_6} & \hat{x_7} & \hat{x_8} & \hat{x_9} & \hat{x_{10}} & \hat{x_{11}} & \hat{x_{12}} & \hat{x_{13}} & \hat{x_{14}} & \hat{x_{15}} & \hat{x_{16}} & \hat{x_{17}} & \hat{x_{18}} & \hat{x_{19}} & \hat{x_{20}} & \hat{x_{21}} \\ \\[-7ex]
\multicolumn{20}{c}{\subfloat[Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{results/ms-rnn.png}}}} \\
\hat{x_2} & \hat{x_3} & \hat{x_4} & \hat{x_5} & \hat{x_6} & \hat{x_7} & \hat{x_8} & \hat{x_9} & \hat{x_{10}} & \hat{x_{11}} & \hat{x_{12}} & \hat{x_{13}} & \hat{x_{14}} & \hat{x_{15}} & \hat{x_{16}} & \hat{x_{17}} & \hat{x_{18}} & \hat{x_{19}} & \hat{x_{20}} & \hat{x_{21}} \\ \\[-7ex]
\multicolumn{20}{c}{\subfloat[Variational Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{results/ms-vrnn.png}}}} \\ \\[-7ex]
\noindent\rule{15cm}{0.4pt} \\
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 & x_8 & x_9 & x_{10} & x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} & x_{15} & x_{16} & x_{17} & x_{18} & x_{19} & x_{20} \\ \\[-7ex]
\multicolumn{20}{c}{\subfloat[Ground Truth]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{results/mm.png}}}} \\
\hat{x_2} & \hat{x_3} & \hat{x_4} & \hat{x_5} & \hat{x_6} & \hat{x_7} & \hat{x_8} & \hat{x_9} & \hat{x_{10}} & \hat{x_{11}} & \hat{x_{12}} & \hat{x_{13}} & \hat{x_{14}} & \hat{x_{15}} & \hat{x_{16}} & \hat{x_{17}} & \hat{x_{18}} & \hat{x_{19}} & \hat{x_{20}} & \hat{x_{21}} \\ \\[-7ex]
\multicolumn{20}{c}{\subfloat[Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{results/mm-rnn.png}}}} \\
\hat{x_2} & \hat{x_3} & \hat{x_4} & \hat{x_5} & \hat{x_6} & \hat{x_7} & \hat{x_8} & \hat{x_9} & \hat{x_{10}} & \hat{x_{11}} & \hat{x_{12}} & \hat{x_{13}} & \hat{x_{14}} & \hat{x_{15}} & \hat{x_{16}} & \hat{x_{17}} & \hat{x_{18}} & \hat{x_{19}} & \hat{x_{20}} & \hat{x_{21}} \\ \\[-7ex]
\multicolumn{20}{c}{\subfloat[Variational Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{results/mm-vrnn.png}}}} \\ \\[-7ex]
\noindent\rule{15cm}{0.4pt} \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{}
\label{fig:qualitative}
\end{figure}
```

error here

```
(no line number):
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
The style file: IEEEtran.bst
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated wiz_functions (elt_size=4) to 6000 items from 3000.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Database file #1: sample.bib
Repeated entry---line 81 of file sample.bib
 : @article{videoanalysis
 :                       ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 162 of file sample.bib
 : @article{vrnn
 :              ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
-- IEEEtran.bst version 1.14 (2015/08/26) by Michael Shell.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/
-- See the "IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf" manual for usage information.
Name 6 in "Jeff Donahue and Lisa Anne Hendricks and Marcus Rohrbach and Subhashini Venugopalan and Sergio Guadarrama and Kate Saenko, and Trevor Darrell" has a comma at the end for entry videoanalysis
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 2 in "Ilya Sutskever and James Martens, and Geoffrey Hinton" has a comma at the end for entry textgen
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 2 in "Ilya Sutskever and Oriol Vinyals, and Quoc V. Le" has a comma at the end for entry machinetranslation
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 3 in "Oriol Vinyals and Alexander Toshev and Samy Bengio, and Dumitru Erhan" has a comma at the end for entry imagecaptioning1
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 3 in "Marco Fraccaro and Soren Kaae Sonderbyz and Ulrich Paquet, and Ole Winther" has a comma at the end for entry srnn
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 3 in "Diederik P. Kingma and Danilo J. Rezende and Shakir Mohamed, and Max Welling" has a comma at the end for entry cvae1
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 1 in "Kihyuk Sohn, Honglak Lee, and Xinchen Yan" has a comma at the end for entry cvae2
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 2 in "Nitish Srivastava and Elman Mansimov, and Ruslan Salakhutdinov" has a comma at the end for entry unsupvideo
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst
Name 5 in "Xingjian Shi and Zhourong Chen and Hao Wang and Dit-Yan Yeung and Wai-kin Wong, and Wang-chun Woo" has a comma at the end for entry convlstm
while executing---line 2403 of file IEEEtran.bst

Done.
You've used 21 entries,
            4087 wiz_defined-function locations,
            907 strings with 10379 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 9031 in all, are:
= -- 687
> -- 266
< -- 0
+ -- 124
- -- 62
* -- 399
:= -- 1604
add.period$ -- 42
call.type$ -- 21
change.case$ -- 21
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 21
duplicate$ -- 795
empty$ -- 818
format.name$ -- 81
if$ -- 2003
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 21
missing$ -- 146
newline$ -- 86
num.names$ -- 21
pop$ -- 414
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 2
skip$ -- 678
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 21
swap$ -- 437
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 5
type$ -- 21
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 21
width$ -- 23
write$ -- 190
(There were 11 error messages)
```

Comment: the error you show is an error from bibtex not from latex so unrelated to the code that you show

Comment: POST A COMPLETE MWE. I even put this information into the comment on your last question where I link to the answer -.-

Answer (score 5):

You need `floatpag`. Don't put `\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}` in the middle of a tabular. Put it directly behind `\begin{figure}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\begin{document}
some text

\begin{figure}[p]
\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}
figure HERE

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The error you are showing is not related to the question. It shows a problem in the bib-file.