# Page numbering bottom right for only page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I would like to know, for `\documentclass{article}`, how I can change the page numbering for only one specific page to be on the bottom right instead of being in the bottom center. Currently, I am using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33013/169182) workaround to get rid off the page numbering (as I am facing the same issue of having a "large" table), though I would like have it being displayed in the bottom right, or maybe even in the right, page margin.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An up-front comment: I think it's perfectly acceptable to suppress the printing of the page number on the pages with overly-tall tables -- as long as there aren't a lot of such pages. To suppress the printing of the page number on an ad-hoc basis, just issue a suitable `\thispagestyle{empty}` directive for the page in question.

If, instead, you prefer to print the page number at the right-hand edge of the footer line, I suggest you load the `fancyhdr` package and modify its `fancy` page style along the lines of the following mock-up example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\usepackage{afterpage} % for '\afterpage' directive

% fancyhdr package provides 'fancy' page style, with lots of
% control over headers and footers:
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3] % filler text

\afterpage{% Defer execution until start of next page:
\thispagestyle{fancy} % or '\thispagestyle{empty}'
\begin{table}[p]
\caption{Whatever}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
% body of tabular env.
aaaa & bbbb & cccc \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\clearpage % "flush" accumulated float(s)
} % end of scope of "\afterpage" directive -- page style back to 'plain'

\lipsum[4-10] % more filler text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This does exactly what I was looking for.
However, your up-front comment now makes me even more hesitant to put the page number right instead of dropping it. It was also that it "unnerved" me that I did not know how to put the page number right in case I would want to (as how to drop the number altogether I found quickly such that it seemed to be easier solution, making me feel uncomfortable not knowing how to do it the other way). However, in the moment I still favor putting the number right. Plus, I learned something which I presumably can generalize.

Comment: @Sinistrum - You're most welcome!