# How can I orient a figure in landscape only when it is placed on its own page?

Tags: floats, rotating, landscape

Floats sometimes end up placed on a page of their own. When this happens, I'd like them to be rotated to landscape mode so that they take up the whole page. `sidewaysfigure` from the `rotating` package will force a figure to appear on its own page, rotated 90 degrees. However, I'd like my floats to be placed in with the text, or more than one to a page, if at all possible: ideally, they would only be rotated when they end up as the only figure on a page. Is there a way to do this? Is it even feasible?

Comment: Possibly relevant/useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84310/21344 Caveats/things to change: The answer there does automatic sizing to fit the page, but places the float on its own page by default rather than detecting placement.

Comment: The latex float placement algorithm assumes that the size of the float is fixed, if it is different then many of the tests and assumptions would be wrong and it would take a major rewrite in general although just making page floats always full page probably wouldn't be impossibly difficult (but still not supported out of the box)

Answer (score 1):

The latex float placement algorithm assumes that the size of the float is fixed, if it is different then many of the tests and assumptions would be wrong and it would take a major rewrite in general although just making page floats always full page probably wouldn't be impossibly difficult (but still not supported out of the box)