# Include a 100 graphs in 100 slides in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I have a 100 images named `Image-1.pdf` to `Image-100.pdf`. Is there a way to include all of them in one slide each without having to type out each name in 100 slides and doing `\includegraphics` on each slide?

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes, then accept an answer (the one that you like most).

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to implement loops in LaTeX. One possibility is the `pgffor` package (see section 83 "Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement" of the [tikz documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,3}{
        \includegraphics<+>[width=\linewidth]{img/image-\i}
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Beamer comes with a command, which does exactly this: `\multiinclude`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \multiinclude[<+->][format=pdf, graphics={width=\textwidth}, start=1]{Image}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can even animate the sequence using something like `\transduration<0-100>{0.5}`.

Answer (score 2):

My way of doing this is a combined effort of the *filecontents* and *csvsimple* packages. Within the filecontents environment you just list the images to be used (this is helpful when you have no uniform image name pattern).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents,csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\graphicspath{{<insert/path/to/image/folder>}}

\begin{filecontents*}{imagelist.txt}
Image-1
Image-2
Image-3
\end{filecontents*}

\frame{\csvreader[no head]{imagelist.txt}{}{\centering\only<+>{\includegraphics{\csvcoli}}}}

\end{document}
```

Note below (and not part of the original question): if you need automatic portrait/landscape selection of the included images, you might want to look at [Dedicated pages for figures featuring automatic fit-to-page scaling and automatic portrait/landscape selection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84310/dedicated-pages-for-figures-featuring-automatic-fit-to-page-scaling-and-automati/84312#84312)

Comment: You actually don't need `graphicx` with beamer.

Comment: @samcarter Thank you, I wasn't aware of that. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: You can simplify it even more if you use `\includegraphics<+>{\csvcoli}` instead of the `\only` command

Comment: @samcarter And thanks again for helping me improve.