# Suppressing page numbering for table which spans over the entire page

Tags: floats, page-numbering

I want to suppress page numbering on pages with tables which span over the entire page. I tried to do so by putting a `\thispagestyle{empty}` before the table but occasionally the command is applied to the previous page. When I put it after the table, the command is applied to the subsequent page. With some tables this seems to work while with others I encounter this problem. Is there any better way to suppress page numbering on exactly the page where the table is located. I assume that this has to do with the float.

The code goes like this:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\footnotesize  
\scalebox{0.8}{
\centering\makebox[0pt][c]{%
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrrrr}
r&r&r&r&r&r&r&r&r&r&r&r&r\\
\end{tabular}
}
}
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\label{tab_desc_stat01}
\end{table}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: [How to remove header on the page with big picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13307/579)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If it's known that the `table` should go on a page by itself, you should use `[p]` (or `[p!]`) instead of `[htp]` as the location indicator. A `\thispagestyle{empty}` instruction *inside* the `table` environment should then do the job.

Comment: I changed [htp] to [p]. Unfortunately, putting the \thispagestyle{empty} inside the table environment has not resolved it.