# How to set the pagestyle on the page a particular float ends up on?

Tags: floats, header-footer

Sometimes, a float is just a tiny bit too large for one page and one would like to remove the page number and hope that nobody notices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1.02\textheight]{example-image-a}
\caption{This float is too large for one page.}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

(Why, of course this is an artificial example and I could just make the image smaller. This is a more common problem for tables where using a `\resizebox` looks even worse.)
[image: this float is too large]

Unfortunately, no matter where I put the `\thispagestyle{empty}`, there is no way to guarantee that it really affects the page the float ends up on. I tried both before and after the `\includegraphics` and also in the caption itself. There is a way to change the pagestyle for all float pages ([How to remove header on the page with big picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13307/how-to-remove-header-on-the-page-with-big-picture) and `floatpag`) but that's not what I want here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`floatpag`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatpag) also provides `\thisfloatpagestyle` to adjust the page styles *only* for the page of floats it is used in:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatpag,mwe}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
  \thisfloatpagestyle{empty}% empty page style _only_ for this page
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1.02\textheight]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This float is too large for one page.}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: I totally missed that the package can already do that, too. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: `\usepackage{floatpag}` seems also to reset the style of pages with floats only, so, if you use a custom page style, in addition to use `\thisfloatpagestyle{}` to set the page style of floats it is used in, you might need, as I did, to use `\floatpagestyle{}` in the preamble to set back the style of float-only pages to the desired one.