# \thispagestyle{empty} for defined page

Tags: floats, header-footer, page-numbering, sidewaysfigure

I have a sideways figure in a box, that spans a whole page in a twocolumn article.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}


\blindtext[10]
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{
    \includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
    }
    \captionsetup{width=1.33\linewidth}
    \caption{balbla}

\end{sidewaysfigure*}


\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Now the image is bigger than the normal boundaries, so the page numbering is in it. I tried turning it off using \thispagestyle{empty}, but no matter where I put* the command: 
I always remove the page style from either the page *before* or *after* the image page.

The question:

*Is there a command that turns off the numbering for a specific page?*

*I tried before after inside figure, the box below the caption everywhere!

** I have updated the question to include some random text. Putting \thispagestyle{empty} anywhere in \begin{sidewaysfigure*} will delete the page number somewhere in the document, but not at the position where images actually appears - hope the mwe is better now

Comment: I can probably tell you why it doesn't work, but I don't know how to make it work. (It puts everything in a box, but the page style is getting applied to the current page i.e. where the box is saved and not where the box is spat out.)

Comment: Is there a way of creating a command like **thispagestyle** which lets one specifiy **thispage**? I.e. is there away of looking at the source code of thispagestyle, i guess I'd figure a work around if I saw what thispage does...

Comment: You can easily look at the source code. `tex/latex/base/latex.ltx` defines `\thispagestyle`. However, I'm sure somebody will have an automatic best practices solution. I don't, but that doesn't mean nix.

Comment: However, I can copy somebody else's answer ... ;). See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from Werner's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169935/ and works:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
% solution from Werner: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169935/ - question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169908/how-to-set-the-pagestyle-on-the-page-a-particular-float-ends-up-on
\usepackage{graphicx,floatpag,caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}
  \thisfloatpagestyle{empty}
  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[height=0.85\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
  }
  \captionsetup{width=1.33\linewidth}
  \caption{balbla}

\end{sidewaysfigure*}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image: page numbers except on float page]

Comment: @Sebastiano1991 You need an MWE which reproduces the problem. This fixes the case you asked about. If that's not your real case, it isn't much help, but how can we help without being able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I hope this mwe is better now, took me awhile to figure out a problem reproducing mwe.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Remark for future: floatpag will push the numbering of all pages with float objects to the top, i.e. one needs to add \thisfloatpagestyle{plain} for each affected page.