# Custom geometry for page with floats

Tags: floats, margins, geometry

I have a special page for floats (i.e., with `[p]`).
In my real code it is a `longtable` in a `table`. Because of space issues I want to change the margins of the page with that float. How do I set a new geometry only for the float pages?

*This is **not** a duplicate of the linked question as that solution does not work in the case of a float page.*

An MWE with a `\hrule` to indicate the margins of the float page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] 
\begin{figure}[p]
    \hrule
    \caption{A horizontal rule.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `longtable` is for multi-page tables, so it cannot float. You can use something like `changepage.sty`.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner thanks, but that doesn't seem to work, I think because I'm in a float.

Comment: Ok - I read "a special page" so I assumed it is ONE page.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner it is one page, but I don't know which one, so I don't know where to place the `\newgeometry` and `\aftergeometry`. When I place it in the float, nothing happens. By 'special page' I meant using a float with `[p]`.

Comment: I see. Just an idea: `float` package and `[H]` option.

Comment: A `longtable` should *never* be encased inside a `table`. No exeptions. None.

Comment: @Mico the reason was that I wanted multiple columns (so the longtable is not *directly* in the table): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46001/23992 --- But I can also split it up in two separate `tabular`s, if that helps.

Comment: @Keelan - You wrote both "In my real code it is a `longtable` in a `table`" and "the `longtable` is not directly in the `table`". I suspect I'm not the only one who senses a contradiction...

Comment: @Mico I tried to simplify things for this question. That's obviously failing, apologies. The real structure is as in the link I gave in my previous comment: `table` > `multicols` > `longtable` (through a savebox). But I now also have `table` > `multicols` > 2 * `tabular`, if that's better. I think that if I have a way to get the MWE from my post, with the `figure`, to work, I can manage the real case as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to change the page geometry (most likely) it is much simpler and usually sufficient just to allow the content of the float to bleed in to the margins, here by 1cm either side.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] 
\begin{figure}[p]
\hspace*{-1cm}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+2cm}
    \hrule
    \caption{A horizontal rule.}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{-1cm}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for the horizontal margin. For the vertical margin I would still be interested in something as well. But in my current case that is not necessary; what I now do is set the page style to `empty` ([with `floatpag`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169935/23992)) so that the table doesn't appear on top of the page number, and that's enough for now. Thanks again!

Comment: @Keelan same as horizontal, you can put `\vspace*{-1cm}` or whatever above and below the minipage, so long as you have space to steal without hitting the page number or page head

Comment: It seems like if you want to use `\vspace*{-1cm}` and `\hspace*{-1cm}` at the same time then the `vspace` has to go first before the minipage and second after the minipage.

Comment: @Ubiquitous ????? put the space after or before the minipage depending if you want to change the space before or after the image. ideally of course you would not have either hspace or vspace in a document

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that you have to do `vspace`-`hspace`-`minipage`-`hspace`-`vspace`. At least, if I do `hspace`-`vspace`-`minipage`-`hspace`-`vspace` the `vspace` part doesn't work.

Comment: @Ubiquitous doing hspace and vspace at the same point is pretty odd thing to do (more natural to trim the figure dimensions if the intention is to adjust the figure) but anyway a vspace in horizontal mode  is inserted after the paragraph is broken in to lines, after the line that contains the vspace node. so if you do `hspace 1 vspace 2 minipage 3 hspace 4  ` the vertical space could be at any of 1,2,3,4 depending on the widths involved and where linebreaking happens,