# How to hide specific page number?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I have 2 large table which the page number appears in the last row of them. So I decide to hide the page number while keeping heading.

I have tried `\thispagestyle{empty}` which also hide header as well. So How to hide specific page number?

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[MScThesis,twoside]{thesis}
\PrepareForMainContent
\pagestyle{ThesisPagestyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbp]

    \caption{action list}
    \label{tbl:analysis1}
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{C{5cm}C{2cm}C{2cm}C{2cm}}
        \toprule
        %\hline \rowcolor[gray]{.7}
        A & B& C \\
        \midrule
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\        
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[tbp]

    \caption{action list 2}
    \label{tbl:analysis2}
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{C{5cm}C{2cm}C{2cm}C{2cm}}
        \toprule
        %\hline \rowcolor[gray]{.7}
        A & B& C \\
        \midrule
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\    
        a & b & c \\        
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here are some commands from `thesis.cls`

```
\newcommand{\PrepareForMainContent}{\cleardoubleemptypage\pagestyle{ThesisPagestyle}\mainmatter%

\if@twoside%
\newpairofpagestyles{ThesisPagestyle}{
    \lehead{\leftmark}\rohead{\rightmark}
    \cefoot*{\pagemark}\cofoot*{\pagemark}
}\else%
\newpairofpagestyles{ThesisPagestyle}{
    \lohead{\leftmark}\rohead{\rightmark}
    \cofoot*{\pagemark}
}\fi
```

Comment: How about considering `\enlargethispage{<len>}` (specify a suitable `<len>`) for that page so it would shift the page number down into view?

Comment: Depending on a particular package like `fancyhdr` it is easy to define a page style that still keeps the header but drops the footer (i.e. the page number, in most cases)

Comment: @Werner, How to find suitable <len>?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, How to define page style?

Comment: @user3806649: That depends on your code. Please provide a minimal compilable version of your document that shows your issue with the table overprinting the footer region

Comment: @user3806649: If you need 2 extra lines on the page, use `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}`. It depends on how much space you need.

Comment: @Werner, I need 3 - 5 extra lines on the page but none of them (2 to 5, 10, 20, 50) works for me. also as the table are float I use  it like this `\afterpage{ 
 \enlargethispage{-5\baselineskip} \begin{table}[tbp] ... \end{table }` but the refrence to table is not compile correctly.

Comment: @user3806649: Consider using page styles then; I can't replicate your problem without `thesis.cls`. See [How to set the page style on the page a particular float ends up on?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169908/5764)

Comment: @Werner, So how can I define page style without numbering?

Comment: `thesis.cls` ... really? Which one of the 10000000 billion classes named `thesis` is it?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I upload it at files.fm/u/c47u9mwt