# Images in footer on specific pages

Tags: fancyhdr, includegraphics

I want to include a small logo on particular pages in a large document, in the left hand side of the footer. The way to do this seems to be with `fancyhdr`'s alternate-able styles.

I've gotten close to what I need, but I have 2 questions:

1. The header style for the new logo pages is a direct copy of the IHA-fancy-style, but I have been setting the `\lhead` and `\rhead` on a chapter by chapter basis, and changing the text style. How can I change my current set up to apply the headers to the new pagestyle too?
2. How should I be positioning my `thispagestyle` command, when an image is set to use a full page with the `[p]` parameter of the figure environment? It wants to apply to the page before or after it seems.

I hope this is clear enough, I'm struggling to explain what I'm trying to do in my own head, so I've no idea if this makes sense now!

Here's a MWE of what I have so far (note there is a specific filepath for the logo if people try to re-run the code).

You should see from [this output PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HwTQBdTaTR4ssy6WaYruSHNpBa9-O5L0/view?usp=sharing), that the page with the Logo on, is lacking the headers from the rest of the chapter/document, and isn't the page with the figure on.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\headsep 25pt
\headheight 20pt
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{670pt}

\fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage\ } % Custom footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

\fancypagestyle{augment}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\ } % Custom footer
  \fancyfoot[L]{\raisebox{-0.1cm}{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm, clip, trim={100 100 100 100}]{/path/to/mylogo.png}}
}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}
\lhead{\textsf{Chapter 1}}
\rhead{\textsf{My First Chapter}}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage

\lipsum[2]


\thispagestyle{augment}
\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textwidth, clip, trim={0 0 0 0}, draft]{/path/to/dummy/image.png}
\end{figure}
\newpage

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

The answer below does solve the problem for the minimal case I posted, but raised other issues when I brought it in to the full document.

2 issues mainly:

Firstly, I can typeset the document correctly once, but when it comes to a second time in order to populate the ToC, I'm now getting this error:

```
Undefined control sequence.              # Pointing to my document.toc file
\f@ncycolh ->\sffamily \myleftmark       # I added sffamily to the header in the answer below, but its a valid command
                                   \strut
```

which points to this line in the ToC file, though I can't see that there's anything wrong with it specifically

```
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.3.2}Harvesting}{78}{subsection.3.3.2}
```

Secondly, when I include my Appendix Chapters (even with a `\pagetyle{plain}`) I get this error:

```
Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition.
\new@ifnextchar ...eseverd@d  = #1\def \reserved@a { 
                                                    #2}\def\reserved@vb {#3}\f...
 l.685  ...{Chapter \ref{appendix1}}
```

Comment: Your second question is answered here: [How to set the page style on the page a particular float ends up on?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169908/5764)

Comment: Ah, a good start thanks. And floatpag is compatible with fancyhdr?

Comment: Should be. Have you tried?

Comment: Not yet, not at my computer any more.

Comment: RE: edit - True, \myleftmark and \myrightmark were undefined prior tho \chapter, but that can be fixed easily enough.

Comment: Yep, great that looks to have fixed it. I discovered my second error was because I was tryin to use `\ref{}` in the chapter title, which presumably confused the numbering that it was trying to put in to the header, so I've just done away with it for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified `\@chapter` to automatically set `\myleftmark` to the chapter number and `\myrightmark` to the chapter name.

Note that report class is one sided (default), so there are no even pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt]{report}
\headsep 25pt
\headheight 20pt
\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\newcommand{\myleftmark}{}% reserve global name
\newcommand{\myrightmark}{}% reserve global name

\fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
  \fancyhf{}% remove default
  \fancyhead[L]{\myleftmark}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\myrightmark}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\ } % Custom footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

\fancypagestyle{augment}{%
  \fancyhf{}% remove default
  \fancyhead[L]{\myleftmark}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\myrightmark}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\ }% Custom footer
  \fancyfoot[L]{\raisebox{-0.1cm}{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm, clip, trim={100 100 100 100}]{/path/to/mylogo.png}}
}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}
\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}

\usepackage{floatpag}
\floatpagestyle{augment}

\makeatletter
\let\@oldchapter=\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\@oldchapter[#1]{#2}%
  \xdef\myleftmark{Chapter~\thechapter}%
  \xdef\myrightmark{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{My First Chapter}

\lipsum[1]
\newpage

\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textwidth, clip, trim={0 0 0 0}, draft]{/path/to/dummy/image.png}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-16]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, this combined with @Werner's suggestion of `floatpag` seems to do the job nicely - spoke to soon. This causes some other issues with other document elements I wasn't anticipating. See edits above.

Comment: For some reason it thinks I downvoted this answer, and that vote is now locked unless the answer is edited. If you make a superficial edit or something let me know and I'll try to amend the vote.

Comment: Done.  I've accidentally down voted before too.  Very embarrassing!