# How Can I Set A Custom Header or Footer to Appear With a Specific Float?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

This question:

[How to set the pagestyle on the page a particular float ends up on?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169908/how-to-set-the-pagestyle-on-the-page-a-particular-float-ends-up-on)

Almost answers my question, but not quite.  The floatpag macro \thisfloatpagestyle can set a custom footer for a specific float, *but only if the float appears on a float-only page.*

How can I get a custom footer to occur on whatever page a particular float lands, when that page isn't a float-only page?

-Ryan

Comment: You could do it by using `\pageref`, comparing its output with the current page and deciding upon this. Code would be in the page header/footer for more than a single page, though.

Answer (score 1):

The following uses the approach lined out in my comment. It needs at least two runs to get it right.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{refcount}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\float@foot{}
\newcommand\floatfoot@remove[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \long\def\floatfoot@remove@##1#1##2\endfloatfoot@remove@
        {%
          \gdef\float@foot{##1##2}%
        }%
      \expandafter\floatfoot@remove@\float@foot\endfloatfoot@remove@
    \endgroup
  }
\newcommand\floatfoot[2]
  {%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\float@foot\expandafter
      {%
        \csname float@foot@#1\endcsname
      }%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname float@foot@#1\endcsname
      {%
        \ifcsname r@#1\endcsname
          \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{#1}=\value{page}
            #2%
            \expandafter\floatfoot@remove\csname float@foot@#1\endcsname
          \fi
        \fi
      }%
  }
\fancyhead[C]{\float@foot}
\makeatother

\usepackage{duckuments} % only for dummy content (also randomizes the ducks)

\usepackage{hyperref} % only to test whether it works with hyperref loaded

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\blindduck[1-5]
\begin{figure}% >>>
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%
  \caption
    {%
      a duck%
      \label{fig:duck1}%
    }%
  \floatfoot{fig:duck1}{Page containing a duck}% might be used anywhere before
\end{figure}% <<<
\begin{figure}% >>>
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%
  \caption
    {%
      a duck%
      \label{fig:duck2}%
    }%
  \floatfoot{fig:duck2}{Page containing the second duck}%
\end{figure}% <<<

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that is complex!  I wouldn't have come up with that in a million years. Thank you.

Comment: @R.Battelle only problem could be the parts of the document using different page numbering, because the page counter gets reset there. But if you use `\floatfoot` after those points everything should be fine. Also you might want to introduce some code to handle two different entries on a single page (how should they be displayed?).