# Wait until a page is full, then add an image on the next page

Tags: includegraphics

I have some documents (book, memoir, and article classes) with full-page graphics on their own pages.  When putting in `\includegraphics{foobar.png}`, the graphic will always appear in that position in the text, often leaving lots of whitespace before the end of the page before the graphic.  How do I tell LaTeX to fill the rest of this page with text, stop at the end of the section/subsection/chapter if text runs out, and then put the graphic on the next page?

Comment: Easiest is to use the figure environment with the [p] option.

Comment: `\begin{figure}[tp]\includegraphics{foo}\end{figure}` (see John's comment) will move the image to the top of a page, or place the image on a page of its own if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@John-kormylo and @Johannes-b pointed me in the right direction.  This led me to wonder how to remove the page number on those pages with a full-page graphic.  That answer was here: [How to set the pagestyle on the page a particular float ends up on?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169908/how-to-set-the-pagestyle-on-the-page-a-particular-float-ends-up-on)

This is what I ended up using:

```
\begin{figure}[tp]
\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{foobar}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

It works exactly as I need it.