# Re-positioning or hiding page number when it conflicts with contents

Tags: tables, page-numbering

I have a very big table. And if I convert this to PDF, I found that this big table covers the page number. So the page number looks as if it is inside the table.

I shouldn't change page number position in every page. But only this page.

What I have tried ended up just removing all page numbers in all pages, which is not what I want. How can I reposition page number in this case? If repositioning is impossible, how can I hide it?

Comment: I'd suggest you go with a slightly smaller table so that it fits in the text area (or a table that will break across pages). But if you insist on removing the page number, try `\thispagestyle{empty}` (this will remove all headers and footers).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427572/remove-header-footer-on-page-with-large-figure

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik @John  Thank you! I added `\AddThispageHook{\thispagestyle{empty}}` right before `\begin{table}`. But I got `undefined control sequence` when I tried to convert to pdf. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: @user42459 I'm guessing the error comes from `\AddThispageHook`, which is from the `afterpage` package, so you need to load that. Though without a compilable example that reproduces the issue it's hard to say for sure

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  Thank you again. I already added `\usepackage{afterpage}` to the preamble. Could there be any other reason for this error?

Comment: @user42459 Countless reasons. That's a very common error and many different things can cause it. As I said, without a complete compilable example that raises the same error, I can only guess... Could you at least show me the `.log` file?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  Thank you again. The red-colored part of log file says `! Undefined control sequence.
l.1045 \AddThispageHook
                       {\thispagestyle{empty}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., \hobx'), type I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.`

Comment: @user42459 Sorry, `\AddThispageHook` is from `everypage`, not `afterpage`.